# react-modal not closing when clicking the overlay

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-modal

I'm using [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal)

The documentation mentions that the modal should close when you click the overlay by default.  Even if I set the `shouldCloseOnOverlayClick` prop to true, this still does not work.

I'm not aware of anything that might prevent that event from occurring.

In case this is relevant/indicative of anything (and I haven't figured out why this is showing), I noticed in Chrome Developer Tools that my modal's overlay and content nodes both have an undefined class.  All the CSS classes I have used are defined and working as they should.

Here's the relevant JSX and CSS, please let me know if more context is required.

JSX:

```
return (
    <div className="Modal">
        <Modal
            className={{
                base: 'Modal-content' + ' Modal-InputError-videoURL'
            }}
            overlayClassName={{
                base: 'Modal-overlay'
            }}
            isOpen={true}
            contentLabel="Modal"
        >
            {props.message}
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <button
                className="Modal-button"
                onClick={events.handleCloseModal}
            >
                Close
            </button>
        </Modal>
    </div>
)
```

CSS classes:

```
.Modal-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    z-index: 9998;
}

.Modal-content {
    display: relative;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: rgb(38,38,38);
    border: 1.5px solid rgb(45,45,45);
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 1px;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-right: -150px;
    padding: 24px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.Modal-InputError-videoURL {
    height: 134px;
    margin-bottom: -67px;
    margin-top: -67px;
}

.Modal-button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

isOpen property is statically set to true. You should control its value by keeping isOpen value in your state.

```
isOpen = {this.state.isModelOpen}
```

And in handleCloseModal method you can set its value to false.

```
this.setState({isModelOpen: false})
```

Comment: Even when I set isOpen in state, the modal still fails to close when I click the overlay: 

<Modal
        isOpen={this.state.ModalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
      >

Comment: Can you post closeModal method too?

Comment: Yes @tugce you can view my code here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309673/react-modal-shouldcloseonoverlayclick-not-working

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by using `onRequestClose` (per the docs). It seems that `react-modal` doesn't store `isOpen` in its local state, so I provided a callback to `onRequestClose` that updates the `state` in the parent component, which is subsequently passed down to the modal as a prop.

http://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/examples/on_request_close.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the modal in a certain component but the click overlay close was not working. Then, I moved the modal to the previous component parent, and it started work.

I guess it have to do with z-index, but I am not sure. Sorry for missing details.

Hope it helps you guys!